# Does Sadashiva ride a tortoise?

Tags: vedas, shiva, rituals, shaivism

In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PW3J.jpg) from the Manava Shrauta Sutras, a text associated with the Yajur Veda, a certain ritual for worshiping Shiva is described.  As part of this ritual, the five-headed form of Shiva is supposed to be worshipped.  For those who don't know, the five heads of Shiva are known as Sadyojata, Vamadeva, Aghora, Tatpurusha and Ishana, and according to the Shaiva Agamas they correspond to the five gods Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, Maheshwara, and Sadashiva.

[image]

But the Manava Shrauta Sutras describe the five heads slightly differently:

> With the following five verses the invitation of Rudra is performed.  With the verse: "Newly born etc." ... [Sadyojata] is the seer, Brahma[] his deity, the trishtubh his metre, the swan his riding animal, his face westward, the earth his element[.]... With the verse: "Wealth today, O Savitr, etc." ... Vamadeva is his seer, Vishnu his deity, the trishtubh his metre, Garuda his riding animal, his face northward, the water his element[.]... With the verse: "Homage to Rudra..." [Aghora] is his sage, Rudra his deity, the brihati his metre, the bull his riding animal, his face Southward, the heat his element[.]... With the verse "We worship the primeval spirit..." [Tatpurusha] is his seer, Surya his deity, the gayatri his metre, the horse his riding animal, his face eastward, the wind his element[.]  **With the verse "Him who rules" ... [Ishana] is his seer, sound his deity, the brihati his metre, the tortoise his riding animal, his face upward, the ether his element[.]**

As expected, Sadyojata, Vamadeva, and Aghora are said to correspond to Brahma, Vishnu, and Rudra.  Tatpurusha, on the other hand, is associated here with Surya the sun god, not with Maheshwara.  But I'm interested in the fifth figure mentioned.  My question is, who is the deity that Ishana is said to correspond to, the one referred to as Sabda or "sound" who rides on a tortoise?

Is the word "Sabda" used in the sense of Sabda Brahman, a concept found in Kashmiri Shaivism according to which vibrations of sound are equated with the supreme Brahman?  In any case, as I mentioned above, according to the Shaiva Agamas Ishana corresponds to Sadashiva, although considering that there was a difference in the Tatpurusha case that's not a guarantee.

Are there any scriptures that describe Sadashiva as having a tortoise as his Vahana?  If so, what is the reason for that?

Comment: I think by tortoise some symbolic meaning also is to be found. Like the tortoise Kurma (Bhagavan) is the base of the earth as well as Mandarachala in Samudra Mathana. Here Ishana is the deity of Ether, which is one element that is static, much like the steady Kurma.

Comment: @Surya Well, by that argument you could say the Vahanas of all the gods are symbolic.  I think Hindu scripture literally describes things the way they are.  But in any case, regardless I want to know who it is whose Vahana is being described as a turtle.  It wouldn't be Ishana; look at the other cases.  For instance, Garuda isn't the Vahana of Vamadeva, he's the Vahana of Vishnu who corresponds to Vamadeva.  So in this case, the turtle wouldn't be the Vahana of Ishana, it would be the Vahana of whatever deity ("sound") Ishana corresponds to.  I think it's probably Sadashiva, but I'm not sure.

Comment: But they could be literal **as well as** symbolic. As for the tortoise, the closest deity is Varuna. But he doesn't match the ether aspect.

Comment: @Surya Yeah, both Varuna and Yamuna ride on tortoises, but I doubt Shaivites would ever equate either of them to Ishana, or give them the appellation "sound".

Comment: Tatpurush associated with Sun and Maheshwara... I think as Maheshwara remains as witness of Atman... ie. It is Atma Tatwa... similarly sun is also connected with Atman (Atman tatwa) as Moon is connected with Mind tatwa... I think it is referring to it....

Comment: Sabda is not correct synonym of Sound, it's "dhwani" instead. please edit.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Sabda does mean sound.  There are five Tanmatras: Sabda or sound, Sparsha or touch, Rupa or form, Rasa or taste, and Gandha or smell.  Now Sabda is divided into two categories: Dhvani or unlinguistic sound and Varna or linguistic sound.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: In the line "Homage to Rudra..." [Aghora] is his sage, Rudra his deity, the brihati his metre, the bull his riding animal, his face **downward**, the heat his element" , it should be **Southward**, according to link in question.  I have made correction to this effect. You should excuse me for taking liberty in making correction.

Comment: This question is just a contrived attempt to denigrate Sadasiva since the word doesn't occur in the cited material.  Wiki says Ishana, Tatpurusha, Vamadeva, Aghora and Satyojata are the five faces of Sadasiva.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, the above invocation for ritual, was adopted from the mantras of [Rig Vedic hymn V.47 - dedicated to ***Viśvedevas***](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05047.htm), which are as follows:

> 1.URGING to toil and making proclamation, seeking Heaven's Daughter comes the ***Mighty Mother***: She comes, the youthful Hymn, unto the
>   Fathers, inviting to her home and loudly calling.
>
> 2  Swift in their motion, hasting to their duty, **reaching the central
>   point of life immortal, On every side about the earth and heaven** go
>   forth the spacious paths without a limit.
>
> 3 Steer, Sea, Red Bird with strong wings, he hath entered the
>   dwelling-place of the ***Primeval Father***. A gay-hued Stone set in the
>   midst of heaven, he hath gone forth and guards mid-air's two limits.

We have to remember that Rig Veda describes deep spiritual aspects in esoteric manner.

---

It was mentioned in the material made available at the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PW3J.jpg), that "A brahmin shall meditate correctly on the three-eyed, five-faced, ten-armed,..., bearing half-of the body of ***Uma***,..".

The ***Mighty mother*** and ***Primeval Father*** from Rig Vedic mantras, were suitably adopted to Uma and Sadasiva (arthanArIswara).

---

A [tortoise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortoise) is supposed to be the longest living animal and noted for its perseverance.  In spiritual line, perseverance plays vital role.  Thus, Isana might have been mentioned, esoterically, as travelling on tortoise.